# External Federated Authentication with Open ID connect - when is the best time to Identify the Contact?

Tags: xdb, federated-authentication

I have a custom `IdentityProvidersProcessor` for federated user authentication for a front-end user facing site. I would like to also Identify the user as a Contact when they log in. When is the best time / place to Identify the Contact? I tried it in the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification but the Tracker is not available at this point in the middleware.

Comment: If performance is not a big concern , you could try initlialize tracker on successfull auth

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Comment: Were there any exceptions raised ? The tracker can get initialized from anywhere , not sure if its throwing an exception which is not logged. maybe try debugging the starttracker() to see if its not throwing an exception ?

Comment: No exceptions, just Tracker.Current is still null. I think it makes sense that there would not be the tracker and session available at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I went with in the end is to have a `httpRequestProcessed` pipeline processor that does the following

- Check if the tracker contact is not null and the context user is authenticated
- Check a custom session variable is set of whether this pipeline has run
- Identify the contact and then set the custom session variable is set of whether this pipeline has run